# Facebook Post : what would replace depreciated parameters since July 17, 2017?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

If we look at the [facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/page/feed) about POST on the page feed, we notice the following message:

[image]

However, it isn't written anywhere by which to replace these parameters, which don't work anymore. Has somebody found it ?

I noticed that by replacing **`picture`** by **`source`**, we obtained the photo of the article, but for the other parameters I remain in nothingness.

Comment: Open Graph markup is the only way to specify those values now. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this answer to help people who face to this problem.

First, **read these article** to understand the situation :

1. [Facebook No Longer Allows Custom Link Previews](https://warfareplugins.com/facebook-no-longer-allows-custom-link-previews-need-know/)
2. [This announcement by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2017/06/27/API-Change-Log-Modifying-Link-Previews/)

They done that to avoid fake news directly posted on pages. They want all the news to be linked to website. So you just have to modify the `og:meta` (See [The Open Graph protocol](http://ogp.me/)) in the HTML side.

With the help of the tool "[Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/)", you'll be able to test if your article correctly included the necessary parameters, which were previously entered directly in the PHP.